# Как прикрепить стрелку с собственной стилизацией к точке на карте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api

[image: Привет, как можно сделать так чтобы свой указатель прикрепить к нужной точке на карте и при работе с картой он всегда указывал на эту точку ?]

```
<div class="map__map-block">
   <div id="map__map-item">

   </div>
   <script>
   var map;
   function initMap() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map__map-item'), {
       center: {lat: 41.1157952, lng: -73.5688606},
       zoom: 8
       });
       }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?сallback=initMap"> </script>
    <div class="map__button button">We are here</div>
</div>

.map__map-block {
    position: relative;
}
.map__button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 123px;
    left: 123px;
}
.map__button::after {
    border: medium solid transparent;
    content: "";
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-color: #EF3527 rgba(255, 212, 52, 0) rgba(255, 212, 52, 0);
    border-width: 12px;
    margin-left: -42px;
}
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/324880/

Comment: При верстке сайта возник вопрос как можно прикрепить указатель с собственной стилизацией к определенной точке на карте google так что бы при работе с картой он всегда указывал на нужную точку ?

Comment: В ответе необязательно писать код и готовое решение, просто метод в деталях и инструменты.